# Is 한국어를 해요correct?

Tags: grammar

I am asking this because I saw someone saying it is correct, but I don't think it is. As someone who speaks japanese I would never say 韓国語をする, but instead I'd say 韓国語ができる which is equivalent to 한국어를 할 수 있어.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.  하다 has many usages outside of "do" or "act", including speaking a foreign language.  So 일본어 하세요? (literally 日本語 話しますか？）is a common way of saying "Do you speak Japanese?".  You could also say 일본어 할 줄 아세요? (日本語ができますか？) or even 일본어 대화 가능하세요 (日本語で話することができますか？）but there isn't much difference between them.

하다 and する are similar in their meaning and usage, but that doesn't mean every usage pattern of する carries over to 하다 unchanged.  This is one case of the two diverging in their usage.